# How to find nth derivative

Tags: derivatives

Can anyone help with this question?

> How to find the nth derivative of $$
> e^x(2x+3)^3?
> $$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to edit your post.

Comment: For example ``$\exp(x)$`` and ``$e^x$`` will be displayed as $\exp(x)$ and $e^x$.

Comment: What you ask is rather unclear.

Comment: Did you write $e^{2x}$?

Comment: @Axel I updated the question I hope it clear now... I want the solution to the question above I hope you can help with it. Thank you

Comment: @10209 I updated the question I hope it clear now... I want the solution to the question above I hope you can help with it. Thank you

Comment: @Rahul Okay so $f(x) = e^x (2x+3)^3$? I am quite confused when you write afterwards $f(x) = x e^{2x}$.

Comment: @Axel Please ignore the below fx contents.... Those were not the solution I removed those lines I want to solve that question I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Do you happen to know [general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)?

Comment: @Axel I want to solve this using derivative like  $dy/dx$ or $f'x$ or anything else but not in $\sum$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope this answer can help you.

Let $g : x \mapsto (2x+3)^3$ and $h: x \mapsto e^x$. Hence $f = gh$.

You know that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ you have $h^{(n)} = h$. Moreover, $g^{(k)} =0 $ for $k \geq 4$.

So using Leibniz rule,

$$f^{(n)} = \left(g+ng'+\binom{n}{2}g''+\binom{n}{3} g^{(3)}\right)h$$

$$f^{(n)}(x)=\left((2x+3)^3+6\binom{n}{1}(2x+3)^2+24\binom{n}{2}(2x+3)+48\binom{n}{3}\right)e^x$$

Hence,

$$f^{(n)}(x)=((2x+3)^3+6n(2x+3)^2+12n(n-1)(2x+3)+8n(n-1)(n-2))e^x$$

If you are not convinced, you can try to prove this by induction.

Comment: I accepted your answer I don't know why you downvoted but I not did anything and if you can solve this in a different way if you have them, please show it :) @Axel

Comment: @Rahul This is the most efficient way I have, or you can just compute the first derivatives then try to show your result by induction... Yes I got downvoted and the question got closed. If you post a question in the future, please do your best to include your research effort and try to post a clean post using MathJax.

Comment: Ok I will keep this in my mind and sorry for your downvoted :(  and Thank you so much

Comment: No problem, there are some [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1) on this website, if you want to post later I suggest you to check them. And just out of curiosity why did you take $f(x) = x e^{2x}$ in your first edits?

Comment: I just copy that from the Internet solution. Can it solve it using this $$
f(x),
f'(x),
f''(x)
$$

Comment: Ok, yes that does not help. It would have been better if you really tried to calculate the first derivatives of $(2x+3)^3 e^x$ by yourself and did put them in your post. Well, you know what to do in the future. Best of luck :-)